# JetBrains Idea: exclude package & classes from autocomplete

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I exclude some classes from autocomplete, but not from project?

I'm trying to develop on flash with starling library. The problem is that IDE always suggest me a built-in classes, which I probably don't want to use, even if I import another class.

http://monosnap.com/image/7VRQpIhqIPRK2wgBKp41GOU9i

I'm tried to exclude in a Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import, but it takes no effect on a autocomplete.
May be I can reorder autocomplete suggest, for placing the libraries classes on top?
I'm using idea 12.0.4

Answer (score 14):

Does Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> *Exclude from Import and Completion* help you?

Answer (score 2):

Now in Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html for disabling, but they didn't work for me until invalidating caches and restarting.

Pull up autocomplete, highlight the offending item, then option-return and exclude it, either at the class or method level. Then invalidate caches and restart.