# Exclude gem from autocompletion in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

I don't really use `minitest` in my Ruby projects.

How can I exclude it from being shown in autocompletion options?

Unfortunately it is impossible to remove `minitest` dependency from `Gemfile` because it is part of `activesupport`'s list of dependencies.

[image: minitest autocompletion options]

Related question:
[JetBrains Idea: exclude package & classes from autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485964/jetbrains-idea-exclude-package-classes-from-autocomplete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible, please follow the corresponding issues:

your particular case
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-21335

general approach improvement
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-21334